# Fixed Header, Relative Content issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header, set with a `position: fixed;` - so that when I scroll, the header scrolls with the page. (Similar to Facebook and Twitter).

I've applied the following CSS3 effects to my content/images:-

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/

However, because this effect uses the `position: relative;`, my fixed header scrolls underneath my content/images - when I obviously need it to scroll on-top.

Any idea how I might be able to fix this?

I've set up a JSBin of my code: http://jsbin.com/eyoric/2/edit

Comment: Can't see any images in your jsbin...

Comment: @brbcoding I've added the images to my jsbin

Comment: The header looks to be scrolling over the images to me...? See http://i.imgur.com/HS0Aohr.png

Comment: In what browser are you noticing the issue? I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: @MattB. it seems to be the Jquery I've added to my header to make it fade on scroll that is causing the issue - I havn't added JS to the JSBin:- `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $(window).on('scroll', function() { var nav = $("nav"); if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) { if (!nav.data('faded')) nav.data('faded', 1).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.95); } else if (nav.data('faded')) { nav.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1); } }); }); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding z-index to your header and put it at the top of the page. Check out this page to help you understand how to use z-index. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-index

ADDED REVISION
Change your css to position: absolute; and make your top:0px;

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried playing around with the z-index. I have my header set at `z-index: 1000` but it still doesn't seem to sit on-top.

Comment: Ya I posted this before checking your example. Im looking at it right now.

Comment: When I scroll on your example your images go underneath your header, what browser are you using, and what version. You may be using a old outdated document version.

Comment: I didn't include my javascript file in my JSBin but it's my JS that is causing the issue:-

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
     $(document).ready(function() {
  
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var nav = $("nav");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        if (!nav.data('faded')) nav.data('faded', 1).stop(true).fadeTo(500, .95);
    } else if (nav.data('faded')) {
        nav.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
});

});

   </script>`

Comment: Ok so looking at this it doesnt look like your js is the problem though. I want to make sure im on the same page your header is falling under your main content? If thats the case then take your header off of Fixed, put it on absolute with your header position top:0px; then set its z-index to its highest, problem solved!

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. The issue definitely lies with my JS. Because my header is set to `fadeTo(500, .95)` - for some reason this makes my header fall under my main content. If I change it to `fadeTo(500, 1)` - my content once again scrolls on-top of my main content. The same happens if I completely remove my JS.

Comment: Why not try instead of fadeTo animate or toggle combined with a function indicating css opacity to those numbers.